# 'Row' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, tsx

I am using react-bootstrap components (Row, Col) in a tsx component it some how returned me an error of :
" (alias) class Col<As extends React.ElementType = "div">
import Col
'Col' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its instance type 'Col<"div">' is not a valid JSX element."
it was working fine before today.
any suggestions on how to fix that ?!?

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.